# Installing sdkman on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, sdkman

I'm having trouble installing sdkman on cygwin.  The instructions say to run the command:

```
curl "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

When I run this command in cygwin I get this:

```
$ curl "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:03:56 --:--:--
```

Nothing is downloaded and the connection eventually times out.
Any ideas why this is happening? Maybe related to the firewall or something not being properly installed?  Any solution ideas would be helpful, thanks.

UPDATE:

I tried wget as well and got this:

```
$ wget https://get.sdkman.io
--2018-02-09 13:29:47--  https://get.sdkman.io/
Resolving get.sdkman.io (get.sdkman.io)... 162.243.83.58
Connecting to get.sdkman.io (get.sdkman.io)|162.243.83.58|:443... failed: 
Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2018-02-09 13:30:09--  (try: 2)  https://get.sdkman.io/
Connecting to get.sdkman.io (get.sdkman.io)|162.243.83.58|:443... failed: 
Connection timed out.
 Retrying.

--2018-02-09 13:30:32--  (try: 3)  https://get.sdkman.io/
Connecting to get.sdkman.io (get.sdkman.io)|162.243.83.58|:443... failed: 
Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2018-02-09 13:30:56--  (try: 4)  https://get.sdkman.io/
Connecting to get.sdkman.io (get.sdkman.io)|162.243.83.58|:443...
```

Comment: what about just download the script with `wget https://get.sdkman.io` and run it later ?

Comment: Updated my post to include using wget

Comment: It works for me , so there is probably a network issue or firewall. If you use a browser you should be able to open https://get.sdkman.io/ directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, it ended up being a network issue.  My companies firewall is very selective and I was able to circumvent it with a wireless modem stick.